# elasticsearch failed to start in centos

Tags: elasticsearch, centos

centos 6.7, elasticsearch 5

I have installed the elasticsearch using rpm. But failed to start it.

```
error: permission denied on key 'vm.max_map_count'
Starting elasticsearch: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch: line 198:   875 Killed                  exec "$JAVA" $ES_JAVA_OPTS -Des.path.home="$ES_HOME" -cp "$ES_CLASSPATH" org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch "$@" 0>&-
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set vm.max_map_count to an appropriate value.

see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_maximum_map_count_check.html
and https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4978

Something like should solve your issue:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: When running the command `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
` again I'm getting `error: permission denied on key 'vm.max_map_count'`. I'm in VPS

Answer (score 0):

e.g. edit (vi/vim) /etc/init.d/elastic_search (or however you spell it), and change,

```
CURRENT_MAX_MAP_COUNT=`sysctl vm.max_map_count | cut -d'=' -f2`;
if [ -n "$MAX_MAP_COUNT" -a -f /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count ]; then
    if [ $MAX_MAP_COUNT -gt $CURRENT_MAX_MAP_COUNT ]; then
        sysctl -q -w vm.max_map_count=$MAX_MAP_COUNT
    fi
fi
```